# Pdf not completely showing when i create a pdf, using phantomjs, python, selenium

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have tried to create a pdf from a link , using technologies Python + Selenium + PhantomJS , but i am not getting complete image on after converting it to pdf, please help.My code is given below

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
def download(driver, target_path):
    """Download the currently displayed page to target_path."""
    def execute(script, args):
        driver.execute('executePhantomScript',
                       {'script': script, 'args': args})
    driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', '/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute')
    page_zoom = 'this.zoomFactor = {"50%"};'
    execute(page_zoom, [])
    page_viewportSize = 'this.viewportSize = {width: "210mm", height: "297mm"};'
    execute(page_viewportSize, [])
    page_format = 'this.paperSize = {format: "A4", orientation: "portrait"};'
    execute(page_format, [])
    render = '''this.render("{}")'''.format(target_path)
    execute(render, [])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs')
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    download(driver, "113.pdf")
```

[incorrect pdf getting after running above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Loe7r.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code as it makes it very difficult for others to help you troubleshot it.

Comment: It seems the issue is the window size. Have you tried to enlarge the window size?

Comment: i have set this code driver.set_window_size(200, 68) but not working